# Retrieve value of Jquery autocomplete into Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a jquery autocomplete field in **index.php** page :

```
$html .= '<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags:</label>
    <input id="tags" />
    <div id="tagsname"></div>
</div>';
$html .= "<script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(function () {
        var availableTags = [
            'ActionScript',
            'AppleScript',
            'Asp',
            'BASIC',
            'C'
            ];
            jQuery('#tags').autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#tags').on('change', function () {
            jQuery('#tagsname').html('You selected: ' + this.value);
        }).change();
        jQuery('#tags').on('autocompleteselect', function (e, ui) {
            jQuery('#tagsname').html('You selected: ' + ui.item.value);
        });
    });</script>";
```

And I want to retrieve the value into my ajax call in **ajax.js** file:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "setvalues.php",
        data: {"event": event}
```

The call is made with **setvalues.php** :

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
    }
    $_SESSION['event'] = $_GET['event'];
```

*Note: the ajax function is called onclick with a button.*

So that was the context.
What I am trying to do is get the value from my jQuery input in my Ajax function.

**What I've tried to do :** 
I've put this line :

```
event = jQuery('#tagsname').html(ui.item.value);
```

Into my ajax.js file just before the call to get the value I need but it doesn't work. 
I get this error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError : ui is not defined
```

I suppose there is another way to get the value of my input but I can't find how.

*Note2 : You may notice I've omitted some lines, in my ajax.js file for example. This is for clarity.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get a div value/text, you should try

```
let event = $('#tagsname').text();
```

to set value

```
$('element').text('some _value');
```

Update:

if you want to get input elements value, use jquery val() method

```
$('input_element').val();
```

in your case use,

```
$("#tags").val();
```

Comment: @rn605435 The result will be `You selected: ActionScript` text instead of `ActionScript`. Is that want you wanted?

Comment: @Vaidas, he asked how to get value from #tagname div, not input #tags. 

If he wants to get input value, he can get it using $(input_element).val();

Comment: @BugHunter Did he? I can see the following in the question: What I am trying to do is get the value from my jQuery input in my Ajax function.

Comment: @Vaidas, I helped him with what he had tried to achieve. OP is satisfied.

Comment: @BugHunter All fine, just wanted to point out that he should take value straight from an input rather than taking text from a div. If he's happy, I'm happy :)

Comment: @Vaidas, I thought about that, but I noticed that he was looking for #tagsname, so answered accordingly. You do not look happy, you downvoted this answer :-p

Answer (score 1):

Just use jQuery's [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function on an input element. I created a simplified example where a value of your input is displayed in the alert message. You can do the same in your Ajax call.

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function () {
    var availableTags = [
        'ActionScript',
        'AppleScript',
        'Asp',
        'BASIC',
        'C'
        ];
        jQuery('#tags').autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#tags').on('change', function () {
        jQuery('#tagsname').html('You selected: ' + this.value);
    }).change();
    jQuery('#tags').on('autocompleteselect', function (e, ui) {
        jQuery('#tagsname').html('You selected: ' + ui.item.value);
    });
});

// Click event handler of "Get value" button
jQuery("#getValue").click(function() {
  // Select input element and take it's value using jQuery's val() function
  var selValue = jQuery("#tags").val();
  alert("Selected value: " + selValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags:</label>
    <input id="tags" />
    <div id="tagsname"></div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="getValue">Get value</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It worked to but @BugHunter answers was easier to implement in my case.

Comment: No problem :) but that answer is not really correct. It takes whatever text is in `tagsname` div instead of taking input value